# Efficiently Finding the next Friday The 13th

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to **calculate the date for next Friday the 13th** in Python 3, but Idk how to make it more efficient.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange


def is_friday_13th(date):
    # Returns bool value for the given date if it is Friday The 13th
    return date.day == 13 and date.weekday() == 4


def max_days(date):
    # Returns Number of Days for the given month
    return monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]


def friday_the_13th():
    # Returns next Friday the 13th
    # If today is Friday the 13th, returns today's date.

    today = date.today()
    result = today

    if result.day < 13:
        result += timedelta(days=13-result.day)

    found = is_friday_13th(result)

    while not found:
        result += timedelta(days=max_days(result) - result.day)
        result += timedelta(days=13)

        found = is_friday_13th(result)

    return f"{result.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(friday_the_13th())
```

I feel like using the `monthrange` function of the `calendar` module makes it less efficient and this problem can be solved without it but I'm struggling to do it.

I read the solutions written by others and I don't understand how to solve this problem more efficiently and write more Pythonically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def friday13s(from_date=date.today()):
    d = from_date + timedelta(13 - from_date.day)   # clamp date to the 13th

    def increment_month(d):
        mm = 1 if d.month == 12 else d.month + 1
        yy = d.year + 1 if mm == 1 else d.year
        return date(yy, mm, d.day)

    if from_date > d:
        d = increment_month(d)

    while True:
        if d.weekday() == 4:
            yield d
        d = increment_month(d)
```

usage:

```
from itertools import islice

for d in islice(friday13s(), 10):
    print(d)
```

prints

```
2021-08-13
2022-05-13
2023-01-13
2023-10-13
2024-09-13
2024-12-13
2025-06-13
2026-02-13
2026-03-13
2026-11-13
```

Note that `increment_month()` ***is not a general-purpose way to increment the month in a date***. It works fine if the day is the 13th, but it will fail if the day is >= 29th. ***It's only fit for the purpose of the particular task it is used in here***.

There are more elegant ways of incrementing the month with libraries like [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/), but when using only built-ins from the Python standard library, doing some legwork is necessary. Luckily, the date arithmetic for this task is not complicated. Adding a whole extra library just to reduce the above by two or three lines seems excessive.

Comment: @Tomerikoo It wasn't unhelpful. I've moved the gist of it to the answer.

Comment: Yep that last paragraph addition makes it very clear and justified :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yeah I guess you can't add enough emphasis  to the cautionary paragraph. But I'm sure people will copy it anyway.